# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppModule (?) After set a middleware

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I try to follow the documentation of nestjs  [middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) and I have a problem on my nest application after adding and set a middleware.
I've seen the FAQ about the same [common error](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors) from nestjs itself but still confused to solve this problem.

**Error on my terminal**

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppModule (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Object is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:230:19)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:184:33)
    at resolveParam (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:106:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:121:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:52:9)
    at Injector.loadProvider (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:74:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:44:9)
    at c:\codelab\nestlab\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:29:13
```

the problem is while I set AuthMiddleware on my AppModule constructor like this

```
  constructor(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({
        path: '*',
        method: RequestMethod.GET,
      });
  }
```

and this my related code.

**AuthMiddleware.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    console.log('AuthMiddleware passed');
    next();
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthMiddleware } from './auth.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({
        path: '*',
        method: RequestMethod.GET,
      });
  }
}
```

Thanks for your attention & your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Object is provider` means that you're injecting using an interface (the `MiddlewareConsumer` one)

If you [read the docs on middleware consumer](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#middleware-consumer), you'll notice that the
`consumer: MiddlewareConsumer` parameter
should be used in `configure` method, not in `constructor`

Also, do this to improve the type checking:

```
class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```